# need a value in all pages in my website, how can it be?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I need an variable value in all pages through out the website, can I use the $_SESSION? or any other way is there?

I am using $_SESSION but some time on some pages the variable is empty.

Comment: Yes you can use sessions or cookies for this purpose. The empty value will be due to any coding problems only.

Comment: Do you have `session_start` on all pages?

Comment: yes, where this should be? on top of pages or before I call the $_SESSION variable?

Comment: in every page place it in first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to debug by this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['your_value'])):
  echo $_SESSION['your_value'];
else:
  echo "value getting empty on"." ".basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])." "."page";
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use session_start() every page